# How to show order total details after order item details in order summary of magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2

[image: Now show checkout summary section]

[image: But i wanted to show this checkout summany section]

How to show order total details after order item details in order summary of magento 2 checkout page

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps described below.

I assume you are using a theme name "**vendor_theme**"

**step 1:**

create a **checkout_index_index.xml** under

***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/***

or

you can place **checkout_index_index.xml** under a module,

For example, let your module name is "**Company_MyModule**" ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout***

File: **checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                         
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>                                                     
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 2:**
Run below commadns from your magento root to  remove static files

```
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/generated
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

[image]